# In k8s, how to let the nodes choose by itself what kind of pods they would accept

Tags: kubernetes

I want one of my node only accepts some kind of pods. 
So I wonder, is there a way to make one node only accept those pods with some specific labels?

Comment: First, the node has no say on what kind of nodes it gets. The easiest way seems to be adding a unique node to the Node and adding the corresponding label to the relevant pods.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature): property of Pods which attract them to set of nodes.
2. [Taints & Toleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) : Taints are opposite of Node Affinity, they allow node to repel set of Pods.

**Using Node Affinity**

1. You need to label your nodes: 
   `kubectl label nodes node1 mylabel=specialpods`
2. Then when you launch Pods specify the `affinity`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: mylabel
            operator: In
            values:
            - specialpods
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
```

**Using Taint & Toleration**

Taint & Toleration work together: you taint a node, and then specify the toleration for pod, only those Pods will be scheduled on node whose toleration "matches" taint:

1. Taint: `kubectl taint nodes node1 mytaint=specialpods:NoSchedule`
2. Add toleration in Pod Spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  tolerations:
  - key: "mytaint"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "specialpods"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
  containers:
  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
```

Comment: Cool! It's working... Thx. The only problem is when I add the taint to a node, it would not remove the unmatched pod. Any way, I removed them manually, and they didn't come back again. Thx a lot.

Comment: Actually as `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` that's what `IgnoredDuringExection` means that already scheduled Pods will be ignored when label changes.  Glad to learn from you that's the behavior of Tainted nodes as well!

Comment: glad it helped :)